# TestRunner File for Cucumber is not getting executed and not throwing any error

Tags: eclipse, selenium-webdriver, cucumber, testng, test-runner

Whenever I am executing this "**TestNGTestRunner**" file, the file don't get executed and also not populates/throws any error.
This was working fine till sometime, but suddenly it started getting this issue.

[image]

But when I execute the cucumber files individually as shown in below image I am getting the correct result.
[image]

I am expecting that Cucumber files should get executed using TestRunner files

Comment: I was able to fix the above issue, as the "dryRun = true" hence I was getting the above error of TestRunner File for Cucumber not getting executed and not throwing any error.

@CucumberOptions(
features="src\\test\\java\\CucumberFiles\\CreateNewCampaigns.feature",
glue={"StepDefinitions"},
monochrome=true,
_**dryRun=true,**_
plugin= {"pretty","html:cucumberreports\\cucumber.html"},
tags = "@NewCampaignsCreation"
)
public class TestNGTestRunner extends AbstractTestNGCucumberTests{
 
 

}

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix the above issue, as the "**dryRun = true**" hence I was getting the above error of TestRunner File for Cucumber not getting executed and not throwing any error.

@CucumberOptions( features="src\test\java\CucumberFiles\CreateNewCampaigns.feature", glue={"StepDefinitions"}, monochrome=true, ***dryRun=true***, plugin= {"pretty","html:cucumberreports\cucumber.html"}, tags = "@NewCampaignsCreation" ) public class TestNGTestRunner extends AbstractTestNGCucumberTests{ }